# Regex expression (Exclude)

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a regex function that verifies if the email address is valid. All seem to work but this email address "stump_truck@gmail.com" should return 'false' in the condition because it contains underscore. The following is the code that I have written. Is there a way I could exclude underscore(_) from my search?

```
import re

def emailCheck(email):
    result = re.search(r'((A-Za-z0-9.[_])*)@((\d?[a-z]?[A-Z]?)*(\b.com\b|\b.edu\b|\b.org\b))', email)
    return bool(result)
```

Comment: Based on the regex `"((A-Za-z0-9.[_])*)"` as your first half of the email address, it looks like any address that isn't [capital letter, lowercase letter, number, any character, underscore] repeated, will return false. Have you tried rewriting this part of the regex, using something like regex101 as reference?

Comment: The `A-Za-z0-9` at beginning should be a character set (in brackets) and shouldn't be completely optional (`+` instead of `*`). The dot and the character set only consisting of the underscore should be omitted.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy my function is currently returning the stump_truck@gmail.com as True. I have tried it but it's not really working so far

Comment: @michaelButscher I tried doing that but it's returning all the valid email address as false too. For example, it is returning emailCheck("stumptruck@gmail.com") as false.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `(A-Za-z0-9.[_])*`. This is just a optional listing of arbitrary characters `A`, `Z`, `a`, `z`, `0`, `9`, `-`, and `_`.

You need a character class for ranges. It should be `[A-Za-z0-9.]+` and add a start/end line meta escape.

```
^([A-Za-z0-9.]+)@((\d?[a-z]?[A-Z]?)*(\b.com\b|\b.edu\b|\b.org\b))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/1Ors2C/1